# How to create overlays in Math text?

Tags: beamer, math-mode, overlays

As a Math text in the beamer frame:

```
\begin{frame}

\[
f(x) = \begin{cases}
1        & (x \leq 1) \\
x^2 - 1  & (x > 1)
\end{cases}
\]

\end{frame}
```

How to create overlay just with the Math text `x^2-1` into another slide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the complete line to be uncovered on the next slide, you could simply use pause. If only `x^2-1` should be uncovered, you can wrap it inside `\visible<2>{...}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\[
f(x) = \begin{cases}
1        & (x \leq 1) \\\pause
x^2 - 1  & (x > 1)
\end{cases}
\]

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\[
f(x) = \begin{cases}
1        & (x \leq 1) \\
\visible<2>{x^2 - 1}  & (x > 1)
\end{cases}
\]

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can any overlay-tag, like `\only`, `\onslide`, can work in math-mod?

Comment: @xaero Math mode as such is not a problem for overlay instructions